# How do I programmatically add a UIImage to a UIImageView then add that UIImageView to another UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

As the title says, I'm trying to create a `UIImage` that will go inside a `UIImageView` (so that I can animate it later) then I want to put that `UIImageView` into another classes `UIView`.

So far my relevant code is:

This is the `viewDidLoad` for my root view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.playerViewController = [[TUKIPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
}
```

And this is the init for the `UIImageView`:

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        playerIdle = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playerIdle.png"];
        playerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:playerIdle];
        self.view = playerView;
    }
    return self;
}
```

It builds and runs with 0 errors.

What am I doing wrong? I don't see the playerIdle.png anywhere. Though I'm betting I'm doing this terribly wrong.

Comment: What is the `UIImageView` custom class name? How you are initiating the imageview?

Comment: The UIImageView is a property of TUKIPlayerViewController. And the UIImageView is being initialized inside the TUKIPlayerViewController's init, where it says playerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:playerIdle];

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your ViewController , add the imageview directly...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   playerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playerIdle.png"]];
   [self.view addSubView: playerView];
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I knew it would be something simple like this :D Huge thank you to everyone for your answers, this helps me greatly :) /relief

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Answer (score 4):

Pls try the below code :

```
- (id)init 
{
     if (self = [super init]) {
         playerIdle = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playerIdle.png"];
         playerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:playerIdle];
         [self.view addSubview:playerView];
     }
return self; 
}
```

Hope this might help you.....

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[self.view addSubview:playerView];` instead of just setting it(`self.view = playerview;`). What I also do most of the times is bringing that subview to the front:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:playerView];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try:
`myUIImageViewObject.image = myUIImageObject;`

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name.png"]];
imagView.frame=CGRectMake(40,130,45,45);

[self.view addSubview:imgView];

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.